# AHK blocked input

Tags: autohotkey

So I am making my script

```html
toggl:=false
while(1){
 if(toggl){
  Send,E
 }
 Sleep, 150
}
!r::
toggl:=!toggl
return
!y::ExitApp,101
```

Problem is that while the loop is running, I can not cancel it because it blocks !y, so I had to restart computer. So any help with this would be nice.

Comment: Hint: use [GetKeyState](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) inside the loop.

Comment: Can you give me exact code, sorry im really new to AHK

Comment: Hint is a hint. You can use it to find an existing answer.

Comment: You should describe what you want your script to do.  While we might be able to infer this by reading your code, we can only guess at how you *want* it to behave.

Answer (score 0):

Set `#MaxThreads 2` to allow each hotkey to run twice, OR:

Use `SetTimer` to allow the hotkey to end and continue your loop in a "Pseudo-Thread".

```
toggle := 0

F12::
    toggle := !toggle
    if (toggle){
        SetTimer, DoLoop, -100
    }
    return

DoLoop:
    Loop {
        if (!toggle){
            break
        }
        ; [Do your stuff here]
    }
    return
```

Comment: that loop-inside-the-loop seems unnecessary, compared with the question

Comment: `SetTimer, DoLoop, -100` is not a loop. The negative value means it only runs once.  
It just launches a "Thread" which does your actual loop, allowing the hotkey to finish, so it can run again while the loop is active, allowing you to terminate the loop with the same hotkey that started it.